# What do you call the person that distributes medication to GPs?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the profession of the person that goes to a medical doctor such as a GP to distribute medicines, instructing the doctor about which medicine to prescribe for what purpose? Thanks.

Comment: In the US it's a "pharmaceuticals sales representative"; the industry likes to call them "pharma reps" or "PSRs" for short, but other folks usually call them "drug reps".

Comment: Although ti's worth pointing out that the medicines distributed by drug reps are samples. The reps don't deliver purchased stocks.

Comment: A friend of mine is a GP - he calls them 'pushers' but I doubt that's what you're after

Comment: Hopefully the doctor does not rely only on reps to know what to prescribe.

Comment: When I was attending university I would deliberately browse books in the bookstores from other departments. You won't find any book on medications to prescribe among the books in the medical section of the bookstore (that would likely just be publicity). So yes, most people don't realize it, but doctors rely on their sales reps' recommendations for their prescriptions (which I think is sad).

Comment: Good point about the medicines being samples. Sometimes doctors will try these out on a few patients to see how these work.

Comment: Then again, I'm no expert, so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It rather depends on perspective. The potential customer will use different names (often less than complimentary) to those used by the seller

**To Customers...**

- Often just 'Reps'
- Drug reps
- Pharma reps
- Or, as a GP friend insists - 'Pushers'

**To the reps and the pharma companies**

Many of these are generic but the following are all genuine job titles for drug reps from a quick trawl of the major job sites from the US, Britain and Australia

- Pharmaceutical sales representative
- Customer Sales & Service Executive
- Pharmaceutical Territory Manager
- Scientific Sales Specialist
- Field Sales - Life Sciences
- Hospital Sales Specialist
- Business Development Manager - Pharmaceutical
- GP & Medical Sales Specialist
- Rx Regional Account Manager

... And so on

Many, many names for what is, essentially, the same job.

Looking around the job sites, it is clear that there are some regional variations - names that you only see in the US for example.

If you want to be safe, I'd go with ***Pharmaceutical sales representative*** that one is used everywhere

Answer (score 2):

in India it is called M.R (Medical Representative). my father is doctor.so usually  many M.R come to visit at our home.